# Adding an alert to login screen Swift

Tags: ios, swift

For some reason I'm having trouble adding an alert to my sign in screen for when the user gets their password and username wrong. So far I have an alert for when there is only one text field filled in but when I click the sign in button if both text fields are populated no alert shows. Can someone help me with that?

```
@IBAction func loginButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    if (self.userEmailTextField.text == "" || self.userPasswordTextField.text == "") {
        var alert = UIAlertView()
        alert.title = "Sign In Error"
        alert.message = "You must enter a username and password"
        alert.addButtonWithTitle("Dismiss")
        alert.show()
        return;
    }

    func checkLogin(username: String, password: String ) -> Bool {
        if ((username == userEmailTextField) && (password == userPasswordTextField)) {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }

    if (checkLogin(self.userEmailTextField.text, self.userPasswordTextField.text)) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("dismissLogin", sender: self)
    } else {
    }
```

Comment: Just for reference, UIAlertView is deprecated in iOS 8. Use a UIAlertController instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use `isEmpty` property of the texts and you should use `UIAlertController` in swift

```
@IBAction func sendLogin()
{
    self.view.endEditing(true)

    if txtPassword.text.isEmpty || txtPassword.text.isEmpty
    {
        let alert = UIAlertController(
            title: "Invalid Login",
            message: "Please fill user and password",
            preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { (action) in 
            // do something when user press OK button, like deleting text in both fields or do nothing
        }

        alert.addAction(OKAction)

        presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return
    }

    // do the login authentication process
}
```